# compiling libpng in visual studio 2010 problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, libpng

I'm having lots of troubles trying to compile libpng 1.5.13 using visual studio 2010.

I downloaded the source, and opened the pre-made projects under `\projects\vstudio`. First it had a lot of bad references to files in a `..\..\..\1.2.5` - I manually imported the files from the 1.2.7 folder (which was a seperate project, I assume it would point to a zlib project that I hence downloaded). Fixing that problem.

Now it complains that it can't find a file in `#include "zlib.h"` - I however didn't find that file? - It should be in the project folder considering the " signs, shouldn't it - or should I also change that include to `..\..\..\1.2.5\zlib.h`?

I tried downloading zlib, however does pnglib wishes to actually compile zlib & not use the static libraries or something? - so should I copy the whole zlib folder into the libpng folder?

Comment: fix the problems once step at a time. First make sure it compiles. When it starts complaining about linking problems you will start to worry the lib files. Also, I suggest keeping separate libraries in their own subfolders. i.e. libpng in its own folder, and zlib in its own. It will be easier to update the source with new software if it's kept that way

Comment: @cha - ok, but HOW do I make it compiles - is compiling libpng so weird no one can actually help? How do I point it to a missing header file - a header file that is not in the package.

Comment: the reason that is not in the package I guess, is that it is not their library, but a third party. That's why you should keep them separately. Keep zlib, libpng, and other 3rd party libraries in separate folders, just add the directories for include and lib files. Just open the project properties in VS2010, and add the folders into VC++ Directories.